# Javascript slide show gallery with sidebar,

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gallery, slideshow

It's common to see on many sites photo gallery like the one in:

http://bit.ly/1qsMmPY

Almost all news site have one.
There is

- a slider with the thumbs of all the photos,
- the foto selected,
- when you select a photo, there is a lightview effect and a sidebar appears with the description
- when you change image, it reloads a new banner, and sends an event to Google analytics
- (social sharing buttons)
- (deep linking)

I found the script for this specific gallery:

http://bit.ly/1qsMVcx

The Huffington post has one based on flexslider

http://bit.ly/1AAwd2g

There are so many galleries very similar on different websites that i wonder if there is a Free version of this script

I am looking for a javascript or jquery plugin or wordpress plugin  with these features do you know any one.
I am going to write a new script, but i feel like i am trying to reinvent the wheeel.

Answer (score 0):

Reinventing the wheel is easier than trying to fit a square in a round hole. You want the slideshow to do a lot for you, and you'll need to at least tweak and build upon a simple slideshow chunk of code. I would use the bootstrap Carousel. You should be able to add the features you want on top of it fairly easily.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel